# Reference product SKU on WooCommerce confirmation page

Tags: plugins

Good morning/afternoon Stackexchange!

Today I've got what is more of a PHP than a WordPress question. A client of mine is working with eBay's enterprise program and they sent along a "pixel test" full of pretty ancient (non-functional) code. I've modified it to output the result that they are looking for with one exception: the code is grabbing the Product ID number instead of the SKU.

We'll start with the current code:
http://pastebin.com/zNeUH8a9

After line 36, the way I figure things, I need to instantiate a new WC_Product class ($productmeta) using the ID passed from the conditional on line 28. I would then do a foreach loop ($productmeta as $product) in order to gain access to $product->sku and assign it to $sku. I'm assuming I'll need to declare $sku as a global variable so that it can be accessed by the output in the next line.

Oh great oracle of wisdom... is there a faster way to access the SKU without instantiating the product class?

Note - this code goes inside of the order test conditional on thankyou.php in WooCommerce

The solution was simple, in the end. After grabbing the item ID, I had to query the product class:

```
$productmeta = new WC_Product($id);
$sku = $productmeta->post->sku;
```

Then insert $sku instead of $id on the output. It took me about 30min to figure that out. Perhaps it'll be useful to someone else in the future.

Comment: Well thanks for the -2 guys. WTH? Guess I'll figure it out myself.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't start your question with *this isn't a wordpress question*, which isn't in scope of WPSE - see [On Topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). So in a way you got lucky this hasn't been closed - just saying.

Comment: Look, it's a WordPress question by virtue of the fact I was asking about a WP plugin but I admit the phrasing could have been improved. With that said, I was asking about how to pull data out of a class, which wasn't strictly WordPress related.

Comment: From WooCommerce 3.0 you should use get_sku() function, like: `$product = new WC_Product($order_item['product_id']); $product->get_sku()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was simple, in the end. After grabbing the item ID, I had to query the product class:

```
$productmeta = new WC_Product($id);
$sku = $productmeta->post->sku;
```

Then insert $sku instead of $id on the output. It took me about 30min to figure that out. Perhaps it'll be useful to someone else in the future. I [placed the final code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zNeUH8a9).