# Echo SKU in WooCommerce Conformation page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am able to display SKU in a single product page using Product Meta data but it looks like same method does not work on Order Conformation page. Is there any way to echo SKU in a order conformation page? I was able to echo product name by using `<?php foreach($order->get_items() as $item) { echo $product_name = $item['name'];} ?>` but it is not working for SKU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$productmeta = new WC_Product($id);
$sku = $productmeta->post->sku;
```

As seen here: [Reference product SKU on WooCommerce confirmation page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/119856/reference-product-sku-on-woocommerce-confirmation-page)